# RxJava operator like amb, but only with valid results

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I want to automatically find a device in an `Android` app. Therefore I would like to make two calls, a network call with `Retrofit`and a non-network call using a custom SDK, at the same time to find out which device the user is using. The app should pick the first result that delivers a valid value.

I use `RxJava` and tried it with the operator `amb` like this:

```
public Observable<LoginResponse> detectDevice(String username, String pwd) {
    return Observable.amb(device1.login(username, pwd), device2.login(username, pwd));
}
```

This seems to work fine if the device that needs to be detected is device1, which uses a network call. But if it is device2 that should be detected, it will return `onError()`, because the `device1.login()` finishes faster and `amb` takes the first `onNext()` or `onError()`. Even though device2.login() delivers a valid result, it will not be taken into account, because it is too slow.

**My question is:** Is there a better way to only take a valid response or another operator? I don't want to use `zip`, because in the future there might be more devices and I don't want to let the user wait until the login request was finished for each device.

Comment: Are the observables returned by your `deviceX.login` effectively singles i.e. do they emit just a single item and terminate (or terminate with an error)?

Comment: They are singles and return both an item of type `LoginResponse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JohnWowUs post inspired me to use `materialize`, but a bit different, this is what I went with:

```
public Observable<LoginResponse> detectDevices(String username, String password) {

    Observable<Notification<LoginResponse>> deviceOneObservable = device1.login(username, password).timeout(2, TimeUnit.SECDONDS).materialize().take(1);
    Observable<Notification<LoginResponse>> deviceTwoObservable = device2.login(username, password).timeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS).materialize().take(1);

    return Observable
            .zip(deviceOneObservable, deviceTwoObservable, new Func2<Notification<LoginResponse>, Notification<LoginResponse>, Pair<Notification<LoginResponse>, Notification<LoginResponse>>>() {
                @Override
                public Pair<Notification<LoginResponse>, Notification<LoginResponse>> call(Notification<LoginResponse> loginResponseNotification, Notification<LoginResponse> loginResponseNotification2) {
                    return Pair.create(loginResponseNotification, loginResponseNotification2);
                }
            })
            .flatMap(new Func1<Pair<Notification<LoginResponse>, Notification<LoginResponse>>, Observable<LoginResponse>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<LoginResponse> call(Pair<Notification<LoginResponse>, Notification<LoginResponse>> notificationNotificationPair) {

                    final Notification<LoginResponse> deviceOneNotification = notificationNotificationPair.first;
                    final Notification<LoginResponse> deviceTwoNotification = notificationNotificationPair.second;

                    //treat 4 different cases of device detection
                    //case1: no compatible device was detected
                    if (deviceOneNotification.isOnError() && deviceTwoNotification.isOnError()) {
                        return Observable.just(new LoginResponse(DeviceType.UNKNOWN));

                        //case2: device1 was detected
                    } else if (deviceOneNotification.isOnNext()) {
                        return Observable.just(new LoginResponse(DeviceType.DEVICE_ONE));

                       //case3:  device2 was detected
                    } else if (deviceTwoNotification.isOnNext()) {
                        return Observable.just(new LoginResponse(DeviceType.DEVICE_TWO));
                       //case4:  error has occurred
                    } else {
                        ... //error handling
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [`materialise`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/materialize-dematerialize.html) operator on any ouput from `login` function and see if it is error, then use  [`takeUntil`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takeuntil.html) operator to silently discard any errors:

```
List<Observable<LoginResponse>> logins = new ArrayList<>();
logins.add(device1.login(username, pwd));
logins.add(device2.login(username, pwd));
Observable.from(logins)
    .materialize()
    .takeUntil((observableNotification) -> {
        return !observableNotification.isOnError();
    }).dematerialize();
```

An improvement would be to add `timeout` if there is no response from any `login` function to throw `Throwable` to `Subscriber`.

Comment: I tried your code sample and changed Observable.from(logins) to Observable.merge(logins), Observable.from(logins) didn't work for me. But it seems that if one call sends an onError, then takeUntil doesn't work always. (the login methods also have other calls they start beforehand, e.g. get authentification token)

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
Observable.mergeDelayError(device1.login(username, pwd), device2.login(username, pwd)).first()
```